# How to store a duration with Doctrine ODM

Tags: php, doctrine-odm

I stored documents which represent events with doctrine. Each `$event` has an `$eventType`. Each `$eventType` has a `$duration`.

For each `$event` I will only store the `$begin` but not the end as it can be calculated with the default `$duration` of its `$eventType`.

**What would be the most elegant way to store the duration with each eventType?**

1. I would choose a **DateInterval** annotation if it existed in doctrine. But it does not.
2. Save the **number of seconds** of the duration as Integer?
3. Any other possibility?

The simplified eventType Model looks like this

```
<?php

 /**
  * Class EventType
  * @ODM\Document(collection="EventType")
  */
 class EventType {

     /**
      * @var $duration int
      * @ODM\Int
      */
     private $duration;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned, you can save the duration in seconds.
It's pretty straightforward to have a getEnd method:

```
/**
* return \DateTime
*/
public function getEnd()
{
  $end = clone $this->begin;
  return $end->add(new DateInterval('PT' . $this->duration . 'S'));
}
```

Or you could store the $end date, and not the duration, which you could also calculate:

```
/**
* return \DateInterval
*/
public function getDuration() 
{
  return $begin->diff($end);
}
```

The tricky thing with date differences is the daylight saving time: sometimes you can have

```
date + 3600seconds == date + 2*3600seconds
```

So you should think what kind of queries you will make for the end date: will you select events lasting (more or less than) a given amount of time, or will you select events ending (before/after/at) a given date?

Second option is more common, so I would store the end date.